# htaccess - rewrite img path (with subdirectories)

Tags: html, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my images are structured like this:

```
/uploads/middle/ex.png
/uploads/thumb/ex.png
```

i will change it to:

`/images/trees/ex_middle.png` and `/images/trees/ex_thumb.png`

it would be nice if i can get also access to them like this:

`/images/ex_middle.png` and `/images/ex_thumb.png`

is this possible ? i tried:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.+)$ uploads/middle/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^images/trees/(.+)$ uploads/middle/$1 [NC,L]
```

but this only works with one path, and i dont know how the rewrite the file name - any suggestions ?

greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/images/(trees/)?(.+)_(middle|thumb)(.+)$ uploads/$3/$2$4 [NC,L]
```

Works by matching fragments of the URL, assuming the suffix of the file base is always `middle` or `thumb` and that `trees/` is optional, it then concatenates using matching of the various chunks

Comment: is it also possible to load `uploads/middle/` if there is no _thumb or _middle suffix?

Comment: You would need a second rule for that,I believe:`RewriteRule ^/images/(trees/)?(.+)$ uploads/middle/$2 [NC,L]` after the previous rule would work. In this instance the first rule wouldn't match, so the second would get executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/([^_]+)_(.+)$ /uploads/$2/$1.png [NC,L]
```

This will support your desired structure of: `/images/ex_middle.png and /images/ex_thumb.png`